# NSLog on Objects (like UIButton, UIView, NSString, NSDictionary) with %@ for their description

Tags: objective-c, ios

Sorry if this question is too simple but it is something that I have always wondered and I would like to hear the opinion of an expert.

I have always used **NSLog(@"%@",object);** to check the string of a **NSString**, or to see what a **NSDictionary** has inside. So I am really curious about if you can use this technique to **NSLog** all objects in objective C.

According to my experience, a **NSLog** to an object who doesn't have text like content will simply give you the instance description, which will be the object class and instance number I think (like an **UIView** or a **UIButton**).

Is there any situation in where I would get an **EXE_BAD_ACCESS** for logging an object (not a structure/primitive variable)? Or can I keep doing this as I have so far?

Thanks.

Comment: You can get a bad access error if the pointer is invalid.  A nil pointer will print as `(NIL)` or some such (I forget exactly what).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can safely `NSLog` any object that inherits from `NSObject`. The [`description`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html) method will be called to produce the output. The default implementation returns the name of the class, but you are free to override `description` on your own objects to produce any text that you think may be of help to you during debugging.

Comment: As a side note, you will get an EXE_BAD_ACCESS if you do this on an unallocated or released object.

Comment: @PRNDLDevelopmentStudios Nice nickname :-) Does it stand for the letters marking positions of an automatic gear shift?

Comment: Actually, the doc for the `description` method is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSObject), in the NSObject protocol doc.

Comment: @PRNDLDevelopmentStudios won't I just get (Nil) as the output instead?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yes it does, haha. Luis: You may, but as a rule of thumb, always make sure your objects are allocated and initialized ([[object alloc]init]; or [object new];) before using them.